# How do I tell TypeScript that it's safe to reference an export that may or may not be available in the current version of a module?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use React's Profiler in Production but the version of React that I am working with is React 16.5 which exports the `unstable_Profiler`.

In the near future another team responsible for delivering an optimized asset bundle (including React) will update to React 17 but I cannot wait for that dependency to be resolved.

However, I don't want the app to break if/when this update goes live.

I tried this:

```
const Profiler = React.Profiler || React.unstable_Profiler;
```

And this:

```
const Profiler = typeof React.Profiler === "undefined" ? React.unstable_Profiler : React.Profiler;
```

But TypeScript correctly points out that:

`Property 'Profiler' does not exist on type 'typeof React'`

**How do I write this line in a way that tells TypeScript this is export may or may not exist and that's OK?**

I would rather not turn off this rule for this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
const Profiler =
  (React as typeof React & {Profiler?: typeof React.unstable_Profiler}).Profiler ||
  React.unstable_Profiler;
```

Comment:  That moment when you copy paste something from StackOverflow and it just works as is  Thanks for the link!